# Create console application that runs as background process and checks folder for new files

Tags: c#, directory, console-application

I have a console application written in C# that iterates a folder containing XML files which it then parses and saves to a SQL via Entity Framework mapping.

After each file is processed I then move the folder to a processed folder location. This is working well in processing all files in the backlog but I am now looking for a method running as a background process and checking for any updates to the folder so that as soon as the file is placed in the directory it is processed

Is there a means of doing this via a console app?

Comment: You are better off using Windows Service, *with a FileSystemWatcher*.

Comment: Scheduled Task? Depending on how responsive it needs to be. The above comment being the most responsive of course.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys I will look into the FileSystemWatcher @habib and will get back to you on this if you want to put this as an answer rather than a comment I will then accept it thanks